# Equality of two spans

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this true ?
span{$(2,2,0),(1,2,1),(1,0,-1)$} = span{$(2,2,0),(1,2,1)$}

I think it is true because $(1,0,-1)$ is a linear combination of the other two vectors above.

Comment: Yes, it's true, your explanation is correct

Comment: You may also combine the five vectors in a matrix and show that the rank of that matrix equals $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As, $(2,2,0)-(1,2,1)=(1,0,-1)$, and since $(2,2,0),(1,2,1)$ are linearly independent . So, $Span\{(2,2,0),(1,2,1),(1,0,-1)\}=Span\{(2,2,0),(1,2,1)\}$, that means, each vector is in linear combination of these vectors $\{(2,2,0),(1,2,1),(1,0,-1)\}$ also a linear combination of these vectors $\{(2,2,0),(1,2,1)\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps they want you to write any vector $a(2,2,0)+b(1,2,1)+c(1,0,-1)$ as a linear combination of $(2,2,0)$ and $(1,2,1)$, and any vector $d(2,2,0)+e(1,2,1)$ as a linear combination of all three vectors.

Comment: It only asks us whether is true or not . But yes, I can write it in either way, and the statement always holds.

Comment: Am I right?????

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$